# Seat issue confirmed or cancelled on Indian Railways?

Tags: trains, public-transport, india, bookings, indian-railways

When I booked my online ticket, my 1 and 2 was waiting list is now 1 and 2 RAC.

- Does this mean my seat was confirmed or cancelled?
- Will I get a seat or not?

Comment: You will get seat (if there are any empty seats) but it will be shared with one more passenger.

Answer (score 2):

RAC stands for **Reservation Against Cancellation**:

> A confirmed berth is allocated to the person who reserves an RAC ticket if passengers who already have a confirmed ticket cancels his/her ticket or do not turn up before the train departure. ... A passenger can cancel RAC online ticket up to 30 minutes before the scheduled departure of the train.

([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjB64udq-TkAhWLIMAKHZPJCAoQFjABegQIDBAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ndtv.com%2Fbusiness%2Firctc-rac-reservation-against-cancellation-online-ticket-booking-cancellation-rules-charges-5-points-1900979&usg=AOvVaw2SxbeFoffDV-X9G2oJma6X))

You will get the seat if the person cancels the seat or doesn’t board the train, shared with one more passenger.

Answer (score 2):

RAC means Reserve against cancellation. Generally, most RAC seats are side lower which is shared with another person.

Side lower seats while sharing with another person might look something like this

[image: seats]